# Using variable in VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to check if my variable occurs in a listobject and if so retrieve the corresponding value.

My code always goes to error at the following line though:

```
shtData.Cells(rowNumber, perf1).Value = wsFunc.IfError(wsFunc1.VLookup(shtData.Cells(rowNumber, cep1).Value, perfTable, 2, False), Null)
```

My code is below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction
Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim wsFunc1 As WorksheetFunction
Set wsFunc1 = Application.WorksheetFunction
Dim cep As Variant
Dim perfTable As ListObject
Set perfTable = perfData.ListObjects("PerfTable")
Dim cepTable As ListObject
Set cepTable = perfData.ListObjects("cepTable")

perfCol = perfTable.ListColumns("Column1").Index
perfSort = perfTable.ListColumns("Column2").Index
cepCol = cepTable.ListColumns("Column1").Index
cepSort = cepTable.ListColumns("Column2").Index

On Error GoTo errHandler

Set usedRange = returnUsedRange(shtData, wb)
Set perfRange = returnUsedRange(perfData, wb)
Set cepRange = returnUsedRange(perfData, wb)

 For Each Row In usedRange
    For Each sec In secRange
        rowNumber = Row.Row
        secRow = sec.Row
            shtData.Cells(rowNumber, perf1).Value = wsFunc.IfError(wsFunc1.VLookup(shtData.Cells(rowNumber, cep1).Value, perfTable, 2, False), Null)
    Next
```

Comment: I don't think you can return `null` to excel like that. You will probably have to return `""` or `0`. It might help to include what the error says though.

Comment: I've tried changing it to "" same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use excel Iferror function like that:

Just use

```
   x = application.vlookup(...,...,...,...)
```

without the WorksheetFunction so you can check Vlookup for errors...

```
   if iserror(X) then ' vlookup failed (x is variant)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this method. Its fast and easy to implement:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrData2Search() As Variant

Set arrData2Search = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1000, 2000)).value


    For i = 1 To 2000
        If arrData2Search (i, 1)= "Target" Then
             ' your code
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Too slow for my requirements. That's what I had to start with and worked fine but it was taking 2-3 mins to run so I was hoping VLOOKUP would improve performance

Comment: vlookup will be, indeed, much faster :) see my answer

Comment: I'm sorry I posted the wrong code. This new code would be just as efficient as VLookUP. Copy the entire range to an array and work with the array

Comment: The array will improve speed, but will still be much slower than match or vlookup. I tested it with a 1000 values range and a match near the end. Match was 9 times faster and vlookup about the same. Let me know if you want the see the code...by the way range.find is many times slower than match, avoid it